# Go: how to get autocomplete for any go file

Tags: go

Seems go has autocomplete data gettable via some go program. any example how to? e.g. i have file `test.go` and line:column 10:12. this pos (10:12) is after some func name, e.g. "getn" - can I get list of all funcs which begin with "getn".

ie, get autocomplete data.

Comment: Is this specifically for your use in a project that works with Go code or are you after a plugin for the editor you are using? `GoSublime` does this for Sublime - and I use`vim-go` for Vim which utilises the `gocode` package for auto completion. Both options are available there (plugins for editors, or `gocode` to create your own autocomplete).

Comment: For my usage of go with my app. not for Sublime/vim (i want to make smth similar to SublimeGo not seeing its code, it's big)

Comment: You should look at the [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) package then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tks to comment. Answer is gocode https://github.com/nsf/gocode (it has document inside zip).